# SVG CodePen not displaying same across browsers?

Tags: html, svg, sass

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/taylor-jeremy/pen/OQmyav) using SVG and SCSS to style two cards in Chrome, and everything displays properly there. However, The internal shapes won't fully display on Edge and Firefox. I tried only using the compiled CSS, but that doesn't fix it. What am I doing wrong? Here is the HTML and compiled CSS:

```css
.svgcontainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#card1 {
  background: lime;
}

.rect1 {
  fill: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.poly1 {
  fill: #fca456;
}

#card2 {
  background: #cd1bc9;
}

.rect2 {
  fill: silver;
  width: 25px;
  height: 140px;
}

.ellipse2 {
  fill: green;
}

.polygon2 {
  fill: #fa4567;
}

.bigshape2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="card1" class="svgcontainer">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="shape-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
        <rect class="rect1" x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" /> 
        <polygon class="poly1" points="25,15 30,20 25,25 20,20" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>

    <!-- use pattern in a circle -->
    <circle class="large-shape" cx="50" cy="70" r="75" fill="url(#shape-pattern)" />
</svg>
<svg id="card2" class="svgcontainer">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="internal-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
        <rect class="rect2" x="12" y="0" />
        <ellipse class="ellipse2" cx="25" cy="22" rx="10" ry="18" />
        <polygon class="polygon2" points="20,10 30,10 25,40" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
  
  <rect class="bigshape2" x="0" y="0"
  fill="url(#internal-pattern)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Wait, different browsers render things differently? I quit... Just kidding, but there are known differences in the capabilities and interpretations of the spec. See [this article for instance](https://opticalcortex.com/svg-rendering-in-browsers/), [or this one](http://niallcardin.com/personal/misc/svgRendering/index.html), [or even this older by still relevant study](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/test-svg-format-browser-engines/). It sucks, but that's life.

Comment: I just find it strange that this of all things is only rendered correctly in Chrome. You would think that this wouldn't be the case for my specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not support the SVG 2 change which allows elements to have sizing set via CSS. Presumably neither does Edge.

Setting width and height via attributes works everywhere.

```css
.svgcontainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#card1 {
  background: lime;
}

.rect1 {
  fill: red;
}

.poly1 {
  fill: #fca456;
}

#card2 {
  background: #cd1bc9;
}

.rect2 {
  fill: silver;
}

.ellipse2 {
  fill: green;
}

.polygon2 {
  fill: #fa4567;
}
```

```html
<svg id="card1" class="svgcontainer">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="shape-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
        <rect class="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" rx="10" ry="10" /> 
        <polygon class="poly1" points="25,15 30,20 25,25 20,20" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>

    <!-- use pattern in a circle -->
    <circle class="large-shape" cx="50" cy="70" r="75" fill="url(#shape-pattern)" />
</svg>
<svg id="card2" class="svgcontainer">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="internal-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
        <rect class="rect2" x="12" y="0" width="25" height="140" />
        <ellipse class="ellipse2" cx="25" cy="22" rx="10" ry="18" />
        <polygon class="polygon2" points="20,10 30,10 25,40" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
  
  <rect class="bigshape2" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="140"
  fill="url(#internal-pattern)" />
</svg>
```